# Stop pygame text from scrolling off screen

Tags: python

I have text that displays the score of a game I created. However I have scrolling screens in my game so eventually the score runs off the screen. How can I keep the text stationary and make sure it stays in the same spot throughout the game?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish for the text to display statically in one location you should simply use an absolute value.

I.e screen.blit(YourTextHere, (0, 0)) will draw 'YourTextHere' at position 0,0 (top left corner of your screen). Regardless of what's actually happening (screen scrolling, cut scene etc)

I imagine currently you're using a variable which changes relative to the position of screen.

If you provide the code for the section in question I can provide a better answer.